# dovecot: enabling a secondary password?

Tags: authentication, dovecot

We're dealing with an unusual situation involving `dovecot` that perhaps requires an unusual solution.

We recently required all of our POP/IMAP users to change their passwords, and in almost all cases, they dutifully did so. However, one user has several devices and machines which are repeatedly querying for email, and due to circumstances beyond anyone's control, one of his computers cannot be accessed for at least another few weeks, and therefore, the `dovecot` password for that user's email access cannot not be changed until that time passes.

Therefore, that computer keeps querying `dovecot` for email for that user with the old, now invalid password, and those queries fail.

Furthermore, due to various circumstances which are also beyond our control for the time being, we can't have that one user change his password back to the old value on the other machines and devices that he uses.

What we're wondering is whether there is some way that `dovecot` could be set up to recognize and accept **both** passwords for this one, specific user. In other words, can we somehow set up a secondary password for this email address so that both the old and the new password will allow this user to access his email?

We are using `auth sql` by including `auth-sql.conf.ext` in `10-auth.conf`. Perhaps the solution to this problem would to restructure the database we are using for SQL authentication and add one or more columns, and then somehow change the SELECT statement that is used in `auth-sql.conf.ext` to choose between one of two passwords.

We are willing to attempt this procedure if it's the only option available, but we aren't even sure how it can be done. And in any case, we're hoping that there might be some feature of `dovecot` that we are unfamilar with which would allow us to set up this one user's `dovecot` email account to allow two different passwords for authentication without any database changes.

Is there any chance that we could do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Super User might be a better community for your question hence my close vote.  That said, https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/multiple_authentication_databases/ talks about multiple databases so it might be as simple as enabled a 2nd database (like password file with that user). Most of the sql backends only give you a user & password.  I would add a 2nd table instead of a column so it's easy to get rid of when done.

Comment: It looks like the sql backends return the password, so I don't think you get to choose which one to return.

Comment: From now on, I'll post questions such as this one in "Super User". I have to say that I keep getting confused as to which forum is the best for any given questions.  As for the sql back end not working for this purpose, yes, I see that it couldn't work. But the good news is that now I have an answer which the link you posted here helped me find. I'm grateful.

Comment: My thinking, and I could be wrong, but this not a programming question but you are trying to configure an application.  No biggie, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link supplied by Allan Wind helped me (thank you!), as well as a couple other things I saw in those `dovecot` docs which I had overlooked in the past.

It turns out that I can supply a second `userdb` and `passdb` block in `auth-sql.conf.ext`, and they serve as secondary fallbacks if the primary SQL query doesn't return a match. I set up a `passwd-file` that is usable by both of these which contains the hash of the user's old password, and now, both passwords are working.

For example, the secondary `userdb` block (which should appear right below the original sql-based `userdb` block) looks like this:

```
# Fallback ...
userdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = scheme=md5-crypt username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/extra.userdb
}
```

The secondary `passdb` block is identical, except for it being named `passdb` instead of `userdb`. It must appear right after the original `passdb` statement in that same file.

So, all's well that ends well.

Onward!